# Which key do I need to press in mission 2 of Tomb Raider 2013?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I am stuck in mission 2 of Tomb Raider, as you can see in the picture below.

What key am I supposed to press at this point?

[image: Tomb Raider fight sequence]

Answer (score 1):

Use the button that you have assigned to melee attacks.

Defaults: F on PC, Y on Xbox and Triangle on Playstation.

Comment: What are the defaults on the relevant platforms? (PS/Xbox/PC)

Comment: @Robotnik I've added them to the answer.

Comment: Perfect thanks :-) and congrats on hitting 3k rep

Comment: But still it does't  work :(

Comment: it worked with E ... !! and thanks for your response !